# Could cuda stream creation cause a data race condition?

Tags: cuda, openmp, nvidia, race-condition

I am now debugging a project, still have not figure out which part is wrong, however I suspect a race condition occurs during the stream creation:

Considering the following code:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
{

  int threadId = omp_get_thread_num();

  cudaSetDevice(threadId);

  cudaStream_t streams[20];

  for (int i=0; i<20; ++i) cudaStreamCreate(streams+i);

};
```

Would that cause a potential race condition, e.g. different thread create streams with the same stream id yet on different device id?

Comment: Can't you just comment out the pragma and see if the problem persists? :) Also, creating streams should be a rare occurrence -- no need to run it parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested to create the cudaStreams in a serial way? You can create the cudaStreams first serially, and then parallelize the code you need.